# is there a way to change colors of a PlacedItem in Illustrator scripting?

Tags: javascript, jsx, adobe-illustrator

I building a simple automation script in Adobe Illustrator, and I am trying to recolor an ".ai" file to match a color swatch on current document template before I embed it to the document. I have tried multiple things all of which didn't work :). I am also not sure where is the right place to recolor before or after embed? i assume before, but since the logo is a [placedItem](https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/jsobjref/PlacedItem.html#:%7E:text=An%20artwork%20item%20placed%20in,object%20is%20a%20placed%20item.) I am not sure if any of the placedItem built in functions would do the task. if not if there are any work arounds?

```
              var logoFile = new File(logoFolderPath + teamID + logoFileExt);
              if (!logoFile.exists) {
                errorFlag = true;
              }
              var logo = doc.layers["ART"].placedItems.add();
              logo.file = logoFile;

              if (logoNeedsToFlip) {
                var myMatrix = getScaleMatrix(-100, 100);
                logo.transform(myMatrix)
              }

              // TODO: Change logo color to match Swatch Color
              //changeLogoColor(logo, swatch_color); 

              // Place the logo within the guide and center and resize
              rotateLogo(logo, guide);
              resizeAndCenterLogo(logo, guide);
              logo.embed();
```

Comment: Alas, as far as I know the answer is 'No'. Probably it can be done via a more serious tool: a custom plugin (C++). But Illustrator's Extendscript API have no such methods and properties. I can be wrong, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Yuri,
I am thinking to either copy the logo (.ai) document make the changes to it, not sure if that will work too.

can you please put me on the right path to develop the a custom plugin ? I am new to illustrator scripting

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to make a plugin. As far as I can tell for your workflow I'd try to make two scripts: 1) InDesign's script saves info about colors and AI files into a TXT file; 2) script for Illustrator, reads info from the TXT file, opens the AI files, recolors  and saves them. After that you can update the links in InDesign.